# Textboxes using BindingSource with more tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, binding, textbox

On my form there is a listbox containing movie titles from table1 and if you select one from the listbox you can see all the movie datas in textboxes bindingsourced from table1.

However i have another table containing + data about the selected movie but i don"t know how can i set the textbox to that because if i simply select the bindingsource from the table2 it won't recognise the movie somehow i need to connect them ...

Can you help me with a solution?

this is how i added the table1 so when user type in textbox it can filter listbox and select the movie

```
var h = from s in db.Filmek where s.Filmcim.StartsWith(textBox1.Text) select s;
            filmekBindingSource1.DataSource = h;
```

But i need the connected data from table2 to show in the textbox too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a join between the two tables?

First create a class for the result of the two tables joined, something like:

```
public class MovieResult
{
      public int MovieId {get;set;}

      public string MovieTitle {get;set;}
      //Other properties of table one

      //Properties of table two
}
```

Then modify your query to look something like:

```
var result = from movie in db.Filmek 
where movie.Filmcim.StartsWith(textBox1.Text) 
join anotherTable in db.OtherTable on movie.FilmId equals anotherTable.FilmId
selecte new MovieResult
{
   MovieId = movie.Id,
   MovieTitle = movie.Title,
   //Fill the properties of table one

   //Fill the properties of table two, ex. if table two contains a field named Country

   Country = anotherTable.CountryName //etc
}
```

Finally bind it to the result:

```
filmekBindingSource1.DataSource = result;
```